# I can't get this array to sort properly. Tried many things

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have tried, and tried and I just dont get how to sort an array. Ive followed countless tutorials to try and get it to sort, but I dont think its working (at least not the way I would like it to).

Im trying to make a high scores table, listing the players ($players) from highest to lowest by score ($totalMoney).

```
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 

    $player  = get_the_author_meta('display_name');
    $cash    = get_the_author_meta('cashOnHand');
    $bank    = get_the_author_meta('bankAccount');

    $totalMoney = $cash + $bank;

    $highScores = array($player => $totalMoney);

    asort($highScores);

    foreach($highScores as $key => $value)

        print_r($highScores);


endforeach;
```

The results are always an array that seems to be sorted by the 'player' field and not the 'scores' field. But no matter what I do, I cannot get it to sort by the 'score' field of the array.

```
 print_r():
Array ( [player3] => 2500 ) Array ( [player2] => 6485 ) Array ( [sd] => 3515 )
```

You can see that the array is not sorted by the scores (I think its being sorted by player names).

How do I get it to sort by the value of the player key?

PS: Ive tried all the various sorts: asort, arsort, ksort, krsort, but its always the same results (see above print_r().

Comment: Is that PHP? If it is, you should say so and tag it. It may affect the answer.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that `$highScores` appears to only have one element in it based on your code. `$highScores = array($player => $totalMoney);` It looks like you are sorting an array with one item every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in your code by reseting the high scores array at every iteration of your loop.

See the following:

```
$highScores = array(); // initialize the array

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
    setup_postdata( $post ); 

    $player  = get_the_author_meta('display_name');
    $cash    = get_the_author_meta('cashOnHand');
    $bank    = get_the_author_meta('bankAccount');

    $totalMoney = $cash + $bank;

    $highScores[$player] = $totalMoney; // add an entry to the array

endforeach;

asort($highScores); // sort the array

print_r($highScores); // see result
```

Comment: Yeah, Flip is right; Move your `asort` outside of your `foreach`.